# Not getting any output while reading the file

Tags: perl

I am trying to read the file from some other directory, it for me every things looks good but unfortunately neither i am getting any error nor any output.

**I am working on windows Pc.**

Here is My code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Cwd;

#chdir('C:\\APTscripts\\APStress\\Logs');
chdir('C:\\Mahi_doc\\Apstress_logs');
my ($dir_01,$dir_02);
my @FILES;
$dir_01 = getcwd;

#print "$dir\n";
opendir(DIR_01, $dir_01) ;
@FILES=readdir(DIR_01);
close(DIR_01);
my $count=12;
my $lines;
for my $dir_02 (@FILES)
{
  #print"$dir_02\n";

 if ( -d $dir_02)
 {
opendir (DIR_02, "$dir_01"."/"."$dir_02") ;
 while(our $file = readdir(DIR_02))
  {
    if($file =~ /APStress.*UIlog/g)
     {
     #  print"$file\n";
       open(FH,$file) or die "can not open the file $!\n"; 
        while (defined(my $lines = <FH>))
        { 
        print"$lines\n";
        if($lines=~ m/WATCHDOG/ || $lines=~ m/Excessive JNI/gi )
        {#chks for watchdog/excessive jni issue exist
          print "Got it\n";
        }
        elsif($lines=~ m/installd: eof/gi)
        {
            print "EOF:Got it  \n";
        }
       }
     }
   }
  } 

}
```

Comment: I have no idea that how to attach the file otherwise i would have attached the log file also which  i am trying to read.

Comment: You are not doing any error checking. So why do you think your script would show any errors?

Comment: die "can not open the file $!\n"; is not giving me any error that means i can say that file is getting open , please correct me if i am wrong. now what else error checking i should perform ?

Comment: May be you haven't any directories under `$dir_01`.

Comment: @42 print"$file\n , files are getting print here .. so i dont think that will be a issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `open` clause, give the full path for the file:

```
open(FH, "$dir_01/$dir_02/$file") or die "can not open the file $!\n";
```

and better use 3 arg open and lexical file handler:

```
open(my $FH, '<', "$dir_01/$dir_02/$file") or die "can not open the file $!\n";
```